# Ошибка при развертывании api на heroku

Tags: heroku, adonis.js

у меня возникла следующая проблема при попытке выполнить следующую команду: node ace migration:run на heroku:

`Error: AdonisJS requires "@adonisjs/assembler" in order to run typescript source directly at Object.registerTsHook (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/core/build/src/utils/index.js:30:19) at App.onFind (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/core/build/src/Ignitor/Ace/App/index.js:132:21) at /app/node_modules/@adonisjs/core/build/src/Ignitor/Ace/App/index.js:161:60 at Hooks.execute (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/build/src/Hooks/index.js:44:19) at Kernel.find (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/build/src/Kernel/index.js:341:30) at Kernel.execMain (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/build/src/Kernel/index.js:162:36) at Kernel.handle (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/build/src/Kernel/index.js:477:24) at App.handle (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/core/build/src/Ignitor/Ace/App/index.js:286:31) at Ace.handle (/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/core/build/src/Ignitor/Ace/index.js:33:9)`

И так же если прописать в Procfile
`release: ENV_SILENT=true node ace migration:run --force`

Всё уже перерыл. То что решает эту проблему не нашёл. Как мне выполнять миграции в таком случае

Answer (score 0):

Проблема насколько я понял была в том что `typescript` находился в `devDependencies`, но он необходим для запуска `ace` команд. Решение оказалось самым банальным. Перенести `typescript` в `dependencies`